# How to use arguments with include directive in Apollo GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, apollo

So for starters, this is my code:

```
export const GET_AUTHORIZED_USER = gql`
    query GetAuthorizedUser(
        $includeReviews: Boolean!
        $after: String
        $first: Int
    ) {
        authorizedUser {
            id
            username
            reviews @include(if: $includeReviews) {
                pageInfo {
                    hasPreviousPage
                    hasNextPage
                    startCursor
                    endCursor
                }
                edges {
                    cursor
                    node {
                        id
                        repositoryId
                        rating
                        text
                        createdAt
                        user {
                            username
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

`reviews` accepts `$after` and `$first` arguments, but my problem is that I cannot figure out how to add them. If I remove `@includes` directive, and add the arguments, it works fine. In my case, I want to have both the directive and the arguments.

How can I achieve this? I know that I can make a separate query for fetching the reviews, but I want to use the directive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, apparently adding the arguments before the `@include` directive is the way. I tried many different ways and this worked like a charm! So if anyone is wondering how to also add arguments besides directives, this is how:

```
export const GET_AUTHORIZED_USER = gql`
    query GetAuthorizedUser(
        $includeReviews: Boolean!
        $after: String
        $first: Int
    ) {
        authorizedUser {
            id
            username
            reviews(after: $after, first: $first) @include(if: $includeReviews) {
                pageInfo {
                    hasPreviousPage
                    hasNextPage
                    startCursor
                    endCursor
                }
                edges {
                    cursor
                    node {
                        id
                        repositoryId
                        rating
                        text
                        createdAt
                        user {
                            username
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

Comment: For some reason this did not work for me at first with React Native, it kept throwing error `Incorrect number of arguments for the @include directive`. I was able to make it work by restarting the Android emulator.